# Get component size from JFrame GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing

Can I obtain the Dimension of a button from a GridBagLayout so I can set a resized icon for that button or should I use other methods to adjust the components position when the window size is changed?

Comment: You have a chicken and egg problem.  The size the button wants to be will be, in part, determined by the size of the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I can set a resized icon

If you want to dynamically resize an `Icon` to fill the space available in the component then check out Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).

The `Icon` will grow or shrink as required as the components size changes. You can have the `Icon` scale proportionally or fill the space available.

Comment: It works butt the image is a lot smaller than the button... :(

Comment: @GeorgiDzhondzhov - you can use something like: `button.setMargin( new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5) );` to control the space or you can use `button.setBorderPainted(false)` to remove the space completely.

Comment: it fills only the text area.The rest of the button is left silver.

Comment: @camickr-Just noting that `StretchIcon` magic class casts the text container as a component and fills only the text field of the button.I added `.getParent` on that same cast in `paintIcon` method and it filled the entire button.